# Computation of product of generalized eigenspace and eigenvectors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My question concerns why $(A-\lambda_1 I)(C_1 v_1 + C_2 v_1^{(1)}) = C_2 v_1$ in the calculations below.

Suppose we have a linear system of differential equations with a constant matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{3x3}$. $A$ has two distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ of which the $\lambda_1$ has algebraic multiplicity $n_j =2$ while $\lambda_2$ has $n_j =1$. The general solution can then be found as

$x(t) = e^{At}x_0 = \sum_{j=1}^{2}\left(\left[ \sum_{k=0}^{n_j-1} (A-\lambda_j I)^k \frac{t^k}{k!} \right] x^{0,j} e^{\lambda_j t}\right)$

Choosing $x_0 = \sum_{j=1}^{2} x^{0,j} = C_1v_1 + C_2v_1^{(1)}+C_3v_2$ we get

$x(t) = e^{\lambda_1 t}(C_1v_1 + C_2v_1^{(1)}) + te^{\lambda_1t}(A-\lambda_1 I)(C_1v_1 + C_2v_1^{(1)}) + C_3 e^{\lambda_2 t} v_2 =\\= e^{\lambda_1 t}(C_1v_1 + C_2v_1^{(1)}) + te^{\lambda_1t}(C_2v_1) + C_3 e^{\lambda_2 t} v_2$

What I don't understand is why $(A-\lambda_1 I)(C_1 v_1 + C_2 v_1^{(1)}) = C_2 v_1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by the definition of [generalised eigenvectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector). In your case, $v_1$ is a generalised eigenvector of rank 1 (which is basically the same as an ordinary eigenvector). This means that it obeys the equation
\begin{equation}
 A v_1 = \lambda_1 v_1 \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad (A - \lambda_1 I) v_1 = 0.
\end{equation}
Generalised eigenvectors form a [Jordan chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector#Jordan_chains). In this case, this means that the generalised eigenvector $v_1^{(1)}$, which is of rank 2, obeys the equation
\begin{equation}
 (A - \lambda_1 I)v_1^{(1)} = v_1,
\end{equation}
such that
\begin{equation}
 (A-\lambda_1 I)^2 v_1^{(1)} = 0.
\end{equation}

Comment: Thank you @frits-veerman, that makes a lot of sense!